# Multiple ListView showing up in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Strangely multiple listview is showing up in my activity. I am trying out on My Nexus 5 and Nexus 5x.

On nexus 5 - it is just one. On nexus 5x - there is no limit. Check the image below: what could be wrong here:

**Nexus 5: Only one Listview.**

[image]

**Nexus 5x - Showing multiple listview:**

[image]

Here is my XML file (specific):

```
<RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/recommendedLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/panelcolor"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonbar"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
                xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
                            android:id="@+id/menuId1Text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/recommendedproduct"
                            android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            pixlui:clearclipboardcontent="true"
                            pixlui:copyandpaste="false"
                            pixlui:typeface="robotoregular.ttf" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
                        android:id="@+id/relatedProduct"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/recommendedLayout"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:divider="@null">
</ListView>
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class RelatedProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductDetails>
{
    private final Context contextValue;
    private final SharedPreferences pref;
    private final String nonetwork;
    ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList;
    private ArrayList<ProductDetails> originalList;
    private ProductFilter filter;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private String productNametext;
    private String casevalue;

    public RelatedProductListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ProductDetails> nameList)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, nameList);
        this.productList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
        this.productList.addAll(nameList);

        this.originalList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
        this.originalList.addAll(nameList);

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        contextValue = context;

        pref = getContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        nonetwork = pref.getString("networkisavailable", getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.yesnetwork));

        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView productName;
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView productCode;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (filter == null)
        {
            filter  = new ProductFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.giftlist_layout, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            LinearLayout mainLinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);

            ProductDetails pd = productList.get(position);

            for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++)
            {
                mainLinnerLayout.addView(getview(productList.get(i)));
            }


            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            return convertView;
    }

    private View getview(final ProductDetails gitem)
    {
        View additionView = vi.inflate(R.layout.ozi_related_product, null, false);

        TextView productName1 = (TextView) additionView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        SquareImageView image = (SquareImageView) additionView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        productName1.setText(gitem.getName());

        Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
                .load(gitem.getImage())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                //.override(250, 250)
                .crossFade()
                .into(image);

        additionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });

        return additionView;
    }


    private class ProductFilter extends Filter
    {

}
```

This is totally strange.. Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to scroll down on Nexus5? Is it possible it's just an "optical illusion" because of the different screen size?

Comment: @Gavriel: Not able to scroll in Nexus 5.. that is the last...

Comment: please post the related code that populates the ListView

Comment: @Gavriel: Done.. please check thanks!

Comment: shouldn't android:layout_below="@+id/recommendedLayout" rather be android:layout_below="@+id/menuId1Text"? Though I don't think it'll fix your problem.

Comment: @Gavriel: menuId1Text is inside relativeLayout..

Comment: ah sorry, you're right, the indentation fooled me

Comment: I think the problem is with the loop inside the overridden `getView()`. This method may be called multiple times for initializing a single view. So, there is a possibility of duplicate items. If you want to add item side by side, why don't you use `GridView`.

Comment: @FarazHussain: I am  using the same method in different activity with 3 listviews and they are showing up and without any issue. Loop is to show values horizontally.. I don't see it called two times.